# Brakes at 2mm, appt. in a week, should I stop driving?

Tags: honda, brakes, maintenance, crv

The brake pads on my 2002 Honda CR-V are at 2mm, which, to my understanding, is quite low. I have an appointment in a week to get them changed. Should I avoid using the car until they are changed?

Answer (score 2):

"Is this safe" questions tend to result in opinions, which often go both ways.   Brake performance is one thing, while emergency performance is another thing entirely.

The car probably stops adequately for normal driving, but potentially less well than maximum effort should the need arise.

It all comes down to your risk acceptance, and whether the vehicle is up to the legal requirements.

We've seen cars that have eaten through their pads and press the metal backing into the rotor, which also damages the rotors.  That's expensive.

If you feel unsafe, minimising or not driving is a perfectly reasonable course of action.  Ultimately its up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll limit my driving as much as possible. The rotors are old and have been re-planed at least once before so they need to be replaced anyway.

Comment: Recommend simply adjusting driving, give more gap in front of you, so you have more breaking space and also have more chance of avoiding emergency breaking where it may become important.

Comment: @Chris I've heard it said "tape a rotten egg to your brake and accelerator pedals" and drive accordingly.